# 'base' as a function parameter name in C#

Tags: c#

I am currently following Microsoft's Naming Guidelines, and so using camelCase in function parameter naming. Now suppose I would like to use the signature

```
public string WriteNumberInBase (int number, int base)
```

in some method and the compiler is complaining about the parameter name just because 'base' is a reserved keyword... Is there any way I can get 'base' to be accepted as a parameter name?

Comment: Well, existing .NET runtime methods, like [Conver.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s62fh68.aspx) uses `toBase` for that parameter, perhaps `inBase` would be a better fit?

Comment: As an alternative, consider `radix`

Comment: Don't do it. Stop being precious and use a different name.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
public string WriteNumberInBase (int number, int @base)
//                                               ^
//                             the @ sign is used to "escape" keywords
```

(As a side note, in VB.NET you would do the same by putting a keyword or reserved word in square brackets, e.g. `[MyBase]`.)

Or alternatively, simply call your parameter [`radix`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix) instead of `base`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Well, since the parameter stands for a (numeric) base I can't figure a better name... Do you remember any?

Comment: @Miguel, I've expanded my answer. *Radix* is an alternative term for a numeral system's base.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `@base`, as others have mentioned.

However, you could also follow the example of [Convert.ToString(int, int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14kwkz77.aspx) which uses `toBase` as the parameter name.

Alternatively, you could use `radix` as a synonym (in context) to base. At that point you might want to change the name of the method too, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Yup.

```
public string WriteNumberInBase (int number, int @base)
```

You'll have to refer to the parameter with `@` sign as well:

```
DoSomethingWith (@base);
```

This looks odd and I advise you to think of a different name.
It looks particularly odd when it's not the only parameter because `@` sign confuses the brain into thinking this parameter is special in some way, when semantically it is not.

Comment: Thank you very much. Well, since the parameter stands for a (numeric) base I can't figure a better name... Do you remember any?

Comment: `toBase` as suggested by Jon Skeet is a very good one, I believe (`inBase` in your case, and shorten the method name to `WriteNumber`).

Answer (score 1):

According to the first paragraph on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx), you can prepend the "@" character to create a valid identifier:

```
public string WriteNumberInBase(int number, int @base)
```

Answer (score 0):

use @base instead of base .... it applies to all keywords ... use @ before the keyword and you will be fine